# Remove "0" at the begininning of phone number with imask.js

Tags: javascript, validation, input, imaskjs

I'm trying to use imask.js for phone validating on subscribe form.

I currently have this simple code :

```
var phoneMask = IMask(
document.getElementById('number_phone'), {
    mask: '+{33}000000000'
});
```

I want to disable the capacity of put a 0 just after the {33} to have this kind of number at the end of the subscription : +33666666666. But allow to put a 0 after the first number.

I've try some Regex but still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a single mask for the whole phone number, we break it into three parts:

```
const phoneMask = IMask(document.getElementById('number_phone'), {
  mask: [
    {
      mask: '+33',
    },
    {
      mask: '9{0}',
      definitions: {
        '9': {
          validator: '[1-9]',
          cardinality: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      mask: '00000000',
    },
  ],
});
```

What the masks does:

1. The prefix `+33` is always present.
2. The first digit after the prefix, which cannot be a `0`. We use a custom definition to only allow digits from `1` to `9`.
3. The rest of the phone number, which allows any digits (including `0`).

The mask will prevent the user from entering a `0` immediately after the `+33` country code but will allow entering a `0` after the first digit.

Comment: Thanks for the details, perfectly worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior by using a regular expression in the mask option of imask.js. Here's an updated code snippet that should work for you:

```html
var phoneMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('number_phone'), {
    mask: '+{33}0-00000000',
    definitions: {
      '0': {
        validate: function (ch, maskset, pos, strict, opts) {
          // Allow 0 after the country code, but not after the leading 0
          return pos === 3 ? /[0-9]/.test(ch) : /^[1-9]$/.test(ch);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples above did not seem to work with `useIMask` react-hook. This one is a bit simpler and works with the hook also.

```js
import { useIMask } from 'react-imask'

// ...

const opts = {
  mask: '+{33}#000000000',
  definitions: {
    '#': /^[1-9]{1}$/
  }
}

const { ref } = useIMask(opts)
```